# find the intersecting line in the provided planes $( 3x+2y+z = -1 ; 2x-y+4z=5)$

Tags: linear-algebra

find the intersecting line in the provided planes $(3x+2y+z = -1 ; 2x-y+4z=5)$. I keep getting the wrong answer, here is my approach:

I set it up in an augmented matrix:

$$
\left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
3 & 2 & 1 & -1\\
2 & -1 & 4 & 5
\end{array}\right]
$$

multiply row 2 by 3 and then minus row 2 by 2row1

$$
\left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
3 & 2 & 1 & -1\\
0 & -7 & 10 & 15
\end{array}\right]
$$

I'm not sure how to row reduce any further so I just put the equations back together and set z to t since its the free variable

$$ 3x+2y+t=-1 $$

$$-7y+10t=17$$

so I get $y = \frac{13-10t}{-7} ; x = \frac{19}{21}+\frac17t; z=t     $

where did I go wrong? the answer in the book states:
$$ x=9t;y=-1+-10t;z=1-7t$$

Answer (score 0):

y = (10t-17)/7, x = (9-9t)/7. In fact, if you let t = 1 - 7a you get the answer in the book.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method here is taking the normal vectors $\mathbf u$ and $\mathbf v$ of the planes and computing $\mathbf w=\mathbf u\times\mathbf v$.
Since $\mathbf w$ is perpendicular to both normal vectors, it is parallel to both planes and hence to their intersection. You can take $\mathbf w$ as the direction vector of the intersecting line.